# How to get the grid size in a Python script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to get the grid size so I can align some vertices to it in a script.  Frustratingly, `bpy.context.space_data.overlay.grid_scale` allows you to set the grid size but not get it.  The overlays tooltip suggests using `bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].overlay.grid_scale`, but this causes an error:

```
>>> bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].overlay.grid_scale
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'overlay'
```

What's a good way to try to get the grid size for my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overlays are set per view.

You need to find the (or a) 3d view area.

```
import bpy

def get_areas_by_type(context, type):
    return [a for a in context.screen.areas if a.type == type]

# Get view3d areas
view3d_areas = get_areas_by_type(bpy.context, 'VIEW_3D')

# Assuming there is one (if not test it in your code)
view3d_area = view3d_areas[0]

# The view space
view_space = view3d_area.spaces[0]

# It has overlay
view_space.overlay.grid_scale = 4.0
```

Or if you know that your context is the 3d view, you can use:

```
context.space_data.overlay.grid_scale
```

Comment: I did not realize the grid was different for each view (which I suppose makes sense since it is part of the Overlay).  ```bpy.context.space_data.overlay.grid_scale``` actually does work in that case then.

Comment: If in the good context, yes. I'll add that, you're right.